# Swift -Firebase how to trigger a TransactionResult.abort() if the ref no longer exists

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

If I want to retrieve some data from Database I can check to see if it exits using `snapshot.exists()`:

```
ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

    if !snapshot.exists() { return }
}
```

But when running a `Transaction`, I just updated something that no longer exists and instead of getting an error, it updated the ref, which I didn't expect.

1- the child ref that the Transaction  is supposed to update:

```
@posts
  @postId_123 // this post has actually been deleted
     -url: ...
     -timeStamp: ...
     -comments_count: 10
```

-2 the user can delete one of their comments without actually viewing it. Once that happens the *comments_count* would decrement.

```
let postsRef = Database.database().reference().child("posts").child("postId_123").child("comments_count")
postsRef.runTransactionBlock({ (mutableData: MutableData) -> TransactionResult in
        
    var currentCount = mutableData.value as? Int ?? 0

    mutableData.value = currentCount - 1
    currentCount = mutableData.value as? Int ?? 0
        
    if currentCount < 0 {
        mutableData.value = 0
    }
        
    return TransactionResult.success(withValue: mutableData)
        
}, andCompletionBlock: { [weak self](error, completion, snap) in
    if !completion || (error != nil) {
        print("The value wasn't able to update")
        print(error?.localizedDescription as Any)
            
    } else {
        print("The value updated")
    }
})
```

3- the issue is if *postId_123* was deleted prior to the Transaction running, the above Transaction results in the *postId_123* being placed back inside the posts ref:

```
@posts
  @postId_123 // this postId has been been put back but should no longer exist
     -comments_count: 0
```

**How can I run a `TransactionResult.abort()` if the child for the mutableData no longer exists?**

```
let postsRef = Database.database().reference().child("posts").child("postId_123").child("comments_count")
postsRef.runTransactionBlock({ (mutableData: MutableData) -> TransactionResult in

    if !mutableData.exists() { // *** this check isn't real and is used just as an example ***

        return TransactionResult.abort() // this is real
    }

    var currentCount = mutableData.value as? Int ?? 0

    // ...
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the only way I found to trigger an abort. If someone posts another way I'll delete this answer.

The first thing to know is that for this answer to work whatever child that you're trying to run the `Transaction` on must have a **value** beforehand and can't be **nil**. An example is if trying to run a `Transaction` on the *comments_count* on a *post*, when the post is first created the *comments_count* has to be created along with it and set at **0** (no comments as of yet). **If there is nothing there then using this method below *comments_count* will NEVER update**:

```
var dict = [String: Any]()
dict.updateValue(postId_123, forKey: "postId")
dict.updateValue(0, forKey: "comments_count") // *** this is important ***
dict...

let postsRef = ...child("posts").child(postId_123)
postsRef.updateChildValues(dict)
```

Then when trying to run a `Transaction` on *comments_count*, if the value is **nil** then the post was deleted (this is assuming there is no other way to delete *comments_count* other than deleting the entire post). If it is **nil** then run `TransactionResult.abort()`. Inside the `completionBlock` you check to see if the `error` is **nil**

```
let postsRef = Database.database().reference().child("posts").child("postId_123").child("comments_count")
postsRef.runTransactionBlock({ (mutableData: MutableData) -> TransactionResult in

    // if nil then the post was deleted
    let checkIfCountExists = mutableData.value as? Int
    if checkIfCountExists == nil {
                
        return TransactionResult.abort()
    }

    // not nil then continue on
    var currentCount = mutableData.value as? Int ?? 0

    mutableData.value = currentCount - 1
    currentCount = mutableData.value as? Int ?? 0
        
    if currentCount < 0 {
        mutableData.value = 0
    }
        
    return TransactionResult.success(withValue: mutableData)
        
}, andCompletionBlock: { [weak self](error, completion, snap) in

    if !completion || (error != nil) {
        print("The value wasn't able to update")
        print(error?.localizedDescription as Any)

        if error == nil {
            print("*** transaction value is nil ***")
            return
        }

        // there is a value there but something else went wrong so try again

    } else {
        print("The value updated")
    }
})
```